# The role of accurate DES FORECASTS for descent planning in VNAV, during the latter stages of an approach

Tags: boeing-737, wind, descent, vnav

Giving an accurate set of criteria in the “DES FORECASTS” page of the FMC helps produce an accurate descent path.

[image]
[image: Typical Descent Profile, Vertical Path]
<sub>*Typical Descent Profile, Vertical Path*</sub>

Adjusting the “TAI ON/OFF” (Thermal Anti Ice), “ISA DEV/QNH” and Forecast Winds will produce an accurate path.

If there is a tailwind and a positive ISA deviation, there will be greater track miles required for the descent, and the Top of Descent point will be moved backwards in space to facilitate this longer descent.

[image]
[image]
<sub>*Adjusted Descent Profile, Vertical Path, due to changes to the DES Forecast Page*</sub>

My query revolves around the practical implications of maintaining precise inputs on the “DES FORECASTS” page, especially during the later stages of approach, from FL080 downwards. While managing the descent above FL100 seems more straightforward—options like selecting a higher speed than FMC target speed when in VNAV SPD mode<sup>1</sup> with possible speedbrake assistance, or modifying the target speed for a steeper descent profile (assuming VNAV mode over LVL CHANGE or V/S)—the approach phase below FL100 introduces complexities. These include the 250 kt speed limitation, STAR speed restrictions, traffic considerations, and deciding the optimal point for deceleration to a final approach speed of 180 kts (as per ICAO standards).

Given these complexities, does inserting an accurate “DES FORECASTS” page offer tangible benefits during the approach below FL80? In my experience, the pilot monitoring frequently updates the LEGS page. As I understand it, these updates inform the FMC of the actual wind and actual temperature, redrawing the descent profile from that point on. Is this practice of refreshing data for the next active waypoint, and potentially overlooking DES FORECASTS inputs, more critical for ensuring an accurate approach phase?

As opposed to [similiar questions asking above the requirement for forecast data to be filled in](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/82346/does-a-vnav-pth-descent-need-the-forecast-descent-winds), this question is trying to understand the forecast page's importance during the latter stages of the approach.

*<sup>1</sup> FMC Version 14.0+ (common VNAV)*

Answer (score 0):

So when we fly the 737 NG we often don't put in this data under FL080. Unless there is a noticeable change in atmospheric conditions like a strong storm or something through the pilots experience that might make him/her do it. There is little difference in terms of decent performance.

And if for some reason you were unstable or unable to meet speed and altitude constraint because you did not input data in below FL080, you weren't monitoring your aircraft well. and that falls more on piloting ability as apposed to automation. (Unless ATC held you high or fast)

Comment: Thank you. But ISA deviation is through the whole descent profile right?